# Specify bit depth in "Save Raster Layer as..." (GeoTIFF)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

Is it possible to change the data type from "Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point" to "Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer"?
I've tried few options, but failed.

[image: Data type]
[image: save raster options]

Comment: Eight bits has a tiny fraction of the range of values in a 4-byte float. "Save As" seems like the wrong interface -- Some sort of calculation would be a better way to map the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the other tool "Raster conversion - Translate". There you can add additional command line parameters which are documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html.

In your case you probably want to use `-ot Byte`. You need a rather new GDAL for signed byte, see https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc87_signed_int8.html

The Save as tool does not work because it has an UI only for the creation options, but selecting pixel type does not belong to the creation options of the GeoTIFF driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Just a little correction: it is `-ot Byte` for getting the OP result. 
QGIS 3.28.9 has the GDAL v. 3.7.1, which is fine!

Comment: Right, I did not read the question well enough but just looked the screen capture where OP had experimented with PIXELTYPE=SIGNEDBYTE.